# How to open navigation drawer on button click in main fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have made an app with one activity which uses a navigation drawer to open a number of different fragments. I have the actionbar drawertoggle, but it is not very visible.
If I place a button in the onCreateView in my main fragment(the fragment that appears when my app first starts up), how can I get it to open the navigation drawer controlled by my activity?

---

This seems to work. The answer is much simpler than I thought it would be.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, container, false);
    button1 = (Button) fragView.findViewById(R.id.button1);         
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    return fragView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       

        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);          

    }
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 77):

if you need open the slide:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //Edit Gravity.START need API 14
```

if you need close the slide

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //Edit Gravity.START need API 14
```

**EXAMPLE**

my mDrawerLayout is instanced here:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
```

my slide state:

```
mSlideState=false;
```

if you need to know the slide menu state (closed, opened). Use this code:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
    mDrawerLayout, 
    R.drawable.ic_menu_slide,
    0,
    0){
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {                       
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    mSlideState=false;//is Closed
}
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {                       
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    mSlideState=true;//is Opened
}});
```

finally. You can use your click event like this:

```
public void clickEventSlide(){
if(mSlideState){                
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
}else{              
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
}}
```

In my case, my slide menu is at the right (Gravity.END), but if you need it on the left, try with `Gravity.START`

Comment: you might consider `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)` instead of flag

Comment: i want this layout above my view. IN THIS THE LAYOUT IS MOVING TO A SIDE. what should i do?

Comment: in your xml, last (bottom-most) declared view will have highest z-index (top) by default, above answer should be accepted if it resolved the issue.

Comment: Everything works fine, but `setDrawerListener` is deprecated must use `addDrawerListener`

Answer (score 21):

### You Should Use [`isDrawerOpen()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout)

The piece of code below automatically closes or opens the navigation drawer based on the drawer's current state (Opened or Closed)

```
Button hamMenu = findViewById(R.id.ham_menu);

hamMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DrawerLayout navDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // If the navigation drawer is not open then open it, if its already open then close it.
        if(!navDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) navDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        else navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are opening the left drawer and closing the right one? Otherwise why you use gravity.start in first line and gravity.end in the second? also why do you use both GravityCompat and Gravity? Just to know if I missed something, because in the documentation gravity is used to identify the drawer.

Comment: @A.Harkous I am not opening the left drawer and closing the right one.  I am using Gravity.START and Gravity.END for the purposes that when the same button is clicked, if the drawer is not open it'll be opened, otherwise if the drawer was already open it will closed. This servers the purpose of utilizing the same button to either close or open the Navigation Drawer based on it's current state. And yesh, using GravityCompat was a typo. Fixed It

Answer (score 4):

if you are using from default navigation activity in android you just have to 
add this code in click listener of button --->

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
```

for closing you do not have to do something.

Comment: This causes the hamburger menu to disappear and be replaced with the Up arrow.

Answer (score 4):

Use these lines to open and close the drawer on a certain event:

### Code snippet for opening drawer:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
```

### Code snippet for closing drawer:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

→ `openDrawer(gravity_of_navigation_view_to_be_shown)`

in openDrawer("gravity"), in "gravity" section, you have to input the gravity of the Navigation View like given above:

```
Gravity.LEFT
Gravity.RIGHT
Gravity.START
Gravity.END
```

I think thats the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

To apply the toolbar as the app bar, first make sure your activity extends from AppCompatActivity. Then call setSupportActionBar() and pass the Toolbar object from your layout:

```
    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);

    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in my opinion

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.navigationViewId))){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```