# Navigation drawer is not open when click on ImageView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to implement navigation drawer, it's working well when i swipe but it's not open when click on ImageView my code is look like below
MainActivity

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
imgMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);

        imgMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```

nav_drawer_material.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/home_details" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In home_details i have took

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />
```

Comment: you are using wrong method: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822591

Comment: @Komal try this  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

Comment: You are using wrong way to do it. you have to useOpenDrawer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241295/7911728)

Answer (score 1):

[isDrawerOpen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen(int)) only checks if the drawer is opened or not. Use [openDrawer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(int)) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

`mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)` actually tells you the state of your drawer and does not change the state of the drawer.

To change the state of the drawer, replace that line with `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
imgMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);

        imgMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```