# Open Navigation Drawer with Button Click

Tags: android, button, navigation, navigationbar

I'm working with Navigation Drawer and I want to click the button on activity and Navigation Drawer should show, but I don't know how to do it. Normally, when we swipe from left edge to the right the navigation will be shown. as such, I want to be able to open the navigation drawer with the click of a button.

Comment: Could you post your code into your question?

Comment: You need to post your code if you need a clearer answer.

Comment: Navigation Bar and Navigation Drawer are different things: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@janishar.ali/navigation-drawer-android-example-8dfe38c66f59

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open navigation drawer on button click in main fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442841/how-to-open-navigation-drawer-on-button-click-in-main-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following methods to open and close your navigation drawer:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

//To Open:
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);

//To Close:
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

[Source1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) for more information:

[Source2](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: i had a variable  private NavigationView navigationBar;btnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              navigationBar.show(); ??????????
                Toast.makeText(PlaylistActivity.this, "CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: @Danh NavigationView is typically placed inside a DrawerLayout so you need to address your navigation drawer.

Comment: i still can't do this. can you please get into detail ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button hamMenu = findViewById(R.id.ham_menu);

    hamMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerLayout navDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            // If the navigation drawer is not open then open it, if its already open then close it.
            if(!navDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) navDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
            else navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a method and Use the exact same steps given by @Zeeshan.

```
public void hamMenu(View view){
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }
}
```

Use this method in the button which you need `android:Onclick="hamMenu"` in `.xml`.