# Unable to open navigation drawer by button click (only by gesture)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am able to show navigation drawer by gesture, but not through button click. Tried with toolbar, does not work still.
Any ideas?

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.cancel);
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
navigation.bringToFront();
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
toggle.syncState();

//code to open on regular button click
if (drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigation);
}
```

Also, onNavigationItemSelected is never ever called when drawer is invoked by gesture. Not sure why, everything is in place (I checked many, many tutorials).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Update:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected:");
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.optionServices) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "optionServices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flags,

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Refer code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241295/5466486) in detail

Would you share the setNavigationItemSelectedListener implementation? you may have not returned boolean value from it properly.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing. This issue is insane.. I added setNavigationItemSelectedListener in text.